# Using ini_set(“memory_limit”, “-1”)

Tags: php, php-ini

I used  `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` in my code php.
I googled it and I searched more, I found that I should change the `"-1"` to increase the size of the memory, but I work directly on the server of production, I change my file then I deploy it.

It have an effect when I upload or download the files ?
It can a cause of the loss of my information when I do the dowload from Highchart ?

Comment: What is you question or issue?

Comment: How is Highcharts related to this? That's a JavaScript library with nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: I have  a loss of information when I download the file from HighChart, I mean by loss information is that the data in the file downloaded not all the data display in the Highchart. And in my code of the parsing the file I wrote ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') , So my question is if I change the size of the memory here for example "1024Mo" instead of "-1" it can change a thing or no ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have set in only on your your script page via php, so it will affect only your script. if you have altered php.ini server file then it will affect entire server memory limit.